# onClick input box, focus on the input box and overlay on the screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am trying to achieve something with HTML and CSS

The initial state of the page should be like the [initialState](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCb0D.png)

onClicking the the search box the state of the page should be [after Onclick](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W7Zw.png)

I am trying to implement it in Angular.

So far what I have implemented is intitalState [implemented initial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tTXdR.png)
and after click [implemented After click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG3s1.png)

```
<div class="search-box" [ngClass]="isOverlay ? 'focus' : 'no-focus'">
  <input class="search-text" type ="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <a class="search-btn" (click)="toggleOverlay()">
    <p class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></p>
  </a>
 </div>


.search-box {
 border-radius: 40px;
 padding-top: 10px;
 height: 60px;
 padding-left: 15px;}

 .search-btn {
  float: right;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;}
```

Overlay html

```
<div *ngIf="isOverlay" (click)="toggleOverlay()" class="overlay-container"></div>
```

overlay css

```
.overlay-container {
 position: absolute;
 left: 0;
 top: 0;
 height: 100%;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: rgba(19, 16, 16, 0.7);
 z-index: 998;}
```

My question is how can I highlight and focus the search textbox when I add overlay currently it hides behind the overlay when I togggle the overlay. I tried z-index to the searchbox onclick but it did not work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like what you'll need to add some css to your search box for when the overlay is active. Essentially you want to update the z-index of your search box so that it's above your overlay.

```
search-box {
  &.focus {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
  }
```